# Help with cross-compiling for ARM

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compilation

I have recently been trying to cross-compile programs for ARM. However, when I run `make`, I always get an error within a minute or less that says something like

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0.
```

The thing that confuses me is that I get that error every time I try to cross-compile a program (except it doesn't always say that it can't find -lgio-2.0. It has trouble finding other things too). Is there something I'm doing wrong? Why is it always this error? The only program I have been able to successfully cross-compile is bash, but I've had problems with everything else. What do I do? I have all of the libraries and things installed, as I am able to natively compile the programs just fine.

Comment: Do you have the ARM versions of any of these packages installed? http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=gio-2.0.so

Comment: @muru No. How do I get ARM versions of packages? My repos only contain AMD64 and i386 packages. (Sorry, I'm new to cross-compiling.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by muru. You need to install the ARM architecture of that library. However they are not listed on http://packages.ubuntu.com site. Neither, it's easy to manage dependencies manually that way.

**Note:** Setup a `chroot` environment, I found weird behavior when I added `armhf` architecture to my Ubuntu 15.04 amd64. I used `dpkg --add-architecture=armhf`. The APT start complaining about broken package `wine` and tried to remove all `i386` packages.

1. Add new sources file

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arm-repo.list
   ```

   Add the source of the architecture you want and release you have.

   ```
   deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty main universe
   ```

   Check for available arch here:  http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/main/ as you can browse up/down for different releases.
2. Update package list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Add a dpkg configuration

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
   ```

   with this line

   ```
   foreign-architecture armhf
   ```
4. Install need packages as needed, example:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0:armhf
   ```

**References:**

- [Getting Started with MultiArch (armel / armhf) in Ubuntu](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/05/02/getting-started-with-multiarch-armel-armhf-in-ubuntu/)
- [Linaro: Cross building Quick Start](https://wiki.linaro.org/Platform/DevPlatform/CrossCompile/CrossbuildingQuickStart)

Comment: Doesn't work with Ubuntu 18.04 (and later). I get `dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'` and `libglib2.0-0:armhf : Depends: libc6:armhf (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed`,... etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download the package, cross-compile it using arm-linux-gnueabihf and place the libraries in the corresponding folders of the arm-linux-gnueabihf compiler directory in /usr/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you [edit] this with more information on how to do that?